# Nestjs Testing Module doesn't injected dependency when using Vitest as test runner

Tags: nestjs, vitest, swc-compiler, nestjs-testing

I can't get the NestJS testing module to work with Vitest, it seems to not inject the services correctly. I got an undefined error when i run tests.

I created two services that I then injected into this service.

```js
import { InjectedOneService } from './injected-one.service';
import { InjectedTwoService } from './intjected-two.service';

export class RandomService {
  constructor(
    private readonly injectedOneService: InjectedOneService,
    private readonly injectedTwoService: InjectedTwoService,
  ) { }
  getStr() {
    return `${this.injectedOneService.foo()} ${this.injectedTwoService.bar()}`;
  }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class InjectedOneService {
  foo() {
    return 'foo';
  }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class InjectedTwoService {
  constructor() { }
  bar() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

Then i wrote this test, it's working fine without testing module

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { RandomService } from './service';
import { InjectedOneService } from './injected-one.service';
import { InjectedTwoService } from './intjected-two.service';
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest';

describe('Service', () => {
  it('should work without testing module', () => {
    const injectedOneMockService = new InjectedOneService();
    const injectedTwoMockService = new InjectedTwoService();
    const result = new RandomService(
      injectedOneMockService,
      injectedTwoMockService,
    );
    injectedOneMockService.foo = vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'mock foo');
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    expect(result.getStr()).toBe('mock foo bar');
  });
  it('should work with testing module', async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [RandomService, InjectedOneService, InjectedTwoService],
    }).compile();

    const injectedOneMockService =
      module.get<InjectedOneService>(InjectedOneService);

    const injectedTwoMockService =
      module.get<InjectedTwoService>(InjectedTwoService);

    const result = module.get<RandomService>(RandomService);

    injectedOneMockService.foo = vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'mock foo');
    injectedTwoMockService.bar = vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'mock bar');

    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    expect(result.getStr()).toBe('mock foo mock bar');
  });
});
```

I got this error

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foo')
 ❯ RandomService.getStr src/vitest-test/service.ts:10:39
      8|   ) { }
      9|   getStr() {
     10|     return `${this.injectedOneService.foo()} ${this.injectedTwoService.bar()}`;
       |                                       ^
     11|   }
     12| }
```

I followed the documentation and installed the SWC plugin to be able to build the test files, and I have no idea where the problem could come from.

Edit :my vitest.config.ts file

```js
    import swc from 'unplugin-swc';
    import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
    
    export default defineConfig({
      test: {
        globals: true,
        root: './',
      },
      plugins: [
        swc.vite({
          module: { type: 'es6' },
        }),
      ],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `RandomService` is missing the `@Injectable()` decorator, which is what forces Typescript (or swc in your case) to emit the decorator metadata that is necessary for Nest to read to know what to inject to which location.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my issue. Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: [There's an open PR](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/2481) and a [blog article](https://trilon.io/blog/advancecd-concepts-dedcorators-and-metadata)